# Image Pixelated When Box Shadow Applied in Firefox Only

Tags: firefox, image, css

So I have this very weird issue I have found. When I apply a box shadow to an image in Firefox, it turns pixelated. When viewed in Chrome, however, the issue is not present. Is this a known issue? My Google results have not yielded anything.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0rku.jpg

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atfu9.jpg

**CSS:**

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Comment: Can you replicate it in a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It was the `-moz-perspective: 600px;` I had set. It caused the pixelation in Firefox, so I replaced it with `-moz-transform: scale(2);` instead and it fixed the issue. Just a small workaround and all is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying

`-moz-box-shadow` in addition to the regular `box-shadow`

```
div.original.selected img{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Comment: The CSS is as follows:
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);  
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);  
box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

Comment: what if you put the image in a div, and applied the box shadow to it instead of the image?

Comment: The image is zoomed with 3D CSS, so it puts the box shadow behind the zoomed image.

Comment: Which I checked and the 3D CSS doesn't affect the pixelation.

Comment: Yep. No shadow, image zooms fine with no pixelation. Add the shadow, it pixelates. With the inspector open, if I disable the CSS zoom, its still pixelated until I disable the shadow.